# How to Efficiently Merge Two Dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python

I want to merge these two dictionaries. The challenge is that not all keys in Dictionary 1 are present in Dictionary 2, and I don't want to lose any data from either dictionary. Additionally, I'm looking for a solution that is efficient because these dictionaries can be quite large.

```
dict1 = {'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'email': 'alice@email.com'},
         'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@email.com'}}

dict2 = {'user1': {'preference': 'dark mode', 'timezone': 'EST'},
         'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}
```

Expected result:

```
merged_dict = {'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'email': 'alice@email.com', 'preference': 'dark mode', 'timezone': 'EST'},
               'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@email.com'},
               'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}
```

Is there a Pythonic way to achieve this, especially one that is efficient for large dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested loop, [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2]
merged_dict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        merged_dict.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

Output:

```
{'user1': {'email': 'alice@email.com',
           'name': 'Alice',
           'preference': 'dark mode',
           'timezone': 'EST'},
 'user2': {'email': 'bob@email.com', 'name': 'Bob'},
 'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to the Python dictionary merging question:

```
dict1 = {'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'email': 'alice@email.com'},
         'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@email.com'}}

dict2 = {'user1': {'preference': 'dark mode', 'timezone': 'EST'},
         'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}

# Merging the two dictionaries
merged_dict = {key: dict1.get(key, {}).copy() for key in dict1}
for key, value in dict2.items():
    merged_dict.setdefault(key, {}).update(value)
```

Comment: Why do you use `dict1.get(key, {})` in the dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score -1):

You should try the code, it should work correctly

```
 dict1 = {'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'email': 'alice@email.com'},
     'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@email.com'}}

 dict2 = {'user1': {'preference': 'dark mode', 'timezone': 'EST'},
     'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}

 merged_dict = dict1.copy()

 for key, value in dict2.items():
     if key in merged_dict:
         merged_dict[key].update(value)
     else:
         merged_dict[key] = value

print(merged_dict)
```

Here is the output of the code
{'user1': {'name': 'Alice', 'email': 'alice@email.com', 'preference': 'dark mode', 'timezone': 'EST'}, 'user2': {'name': 'Bob', 'email': 'bob@email.com'}, 'user3': {'preference': 'light mode', 'timezone': 'PST'}}